# Async code to retrieve documents from dynamodb is never executed

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

The code that should be executed when the DynamoDB finishes is never executed.

Even though I am using scan's built-in promise, the await is not waiting for the scan to finish. Even manually adding an additional await command, it does not get it executed.

```
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update({
          region: "us-west-2",
          endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
        });
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 
        var params = {
                TableName : "residenciaLN",            
            };


    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        console.log("Querying...");

        const load = async () => {
            console.log("Got in...");
            const { Items } = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
            const item = Items[0];
            console.log('Items: ' + item);
            return;
        };
        await load;   // no effect on this line being here or not
        console.log("Exiting...");   
        return 
    }; 

    Actual result:
    INFO    Querying...
    INFO    Exiting...

    Expected result: 
    INFO    Querying...
    INFO    Got in...
    INFO    Items: XXXXXX
    INFO    Exiting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` is a function. To trigger a function call you have to use parenthesis after it.

To make it work, change this line:

```
await load;
```

To this :

```
await load();
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the issue. Hours and hours looking for an answer. Now, if await needs a function, then why the compiler is not failing with some statement? Thanks again.

Comment: By using the statement `await load;`, the javascript engine detects internally that `load` is not a promise (as it is a function), so it is automatically resolved and this statement's parsing is over. This is unfortunately not a syntax issue, that is why you do not have any failure. You can read more in the `await` operator's documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 0):

you need to call load as a function 
`await load()` instead of `await load`

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Querying...");

    const load = async () => {
        console.log("Got in...");
        const { Items } = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
        const item = Items[0];
        console.log('Items: ' + item);
        return;
    };
    await load();   // instead of [await load]
    console.log("Exiting...");   
    return 
};
```

Comment: Thanks! the () was the issue.